# Indesign CS6 print one page

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, cs6

I find it impossible to print only one page of a document.

I select a page in the page menu, right click, but there is no option for print page.  How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

## InDesign CS6

`File > Print`

Then set the page number of the page you wish to print in the **Print Dialog** window, specifically the `Range` field.....

[image]

---

If you are referring to the **Pages Panel** menu... 
The `Print Page` item in the *Pages Panel* is available in **InDesign CC**.
`Print Page` from the Pages Panel is ***not** part of InDesign CS6*.
To "fix" your issue, you would need to *upgrade* to InDesign CC.

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  I had a feeling CC was the deal.  I had a hard time with the regular printing way as above.  But, it is working now after a computer restart.  Might have another issue, but I'm too burnt to write about it now.  Been editing all day and I can't see straight.  Thanks again.  Suzanne